# Use Python to manage content in "Enterprise Architect" software from "sparx systems"

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

Currently i am working with enterprise architect software for creating packages, diagrams.

Is it possible to work in Enterprise architect software using python script ? Some example like Deleting and creating packages and diagrams etc. If so refer example code or link.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that's no problem.

```
import win32com.client
from singleton import Singleton

@Singleton
class Repository:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.eaRep = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App").Repository
            models = self.eaRep.models
            done = True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            done = False
```

(The @Singleton can be found on the net but you can work without it.)
Then in your main program you can access the repository like

```
rep = repository.Repository.Instance()
print rep.modules.getAt(0).name
```

etc. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client

def open_repository(path, login, password):
    eaApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App")
    eaRep = eaApp.Repository
    if login:
        eaRep.SuppressSecurityDialog = True
        eaRep.OpenFile2(path, login, password)
    else:
        eaRep.OpenFile(path)
    return eaRep
```

please use OpenFile for open your model. (OpenFile2 if your model has enabled security)